# Javascript app to stop direct downloads at specified limit

Tags: javascript

Is there a web app available that will stop any direct downloads at a specified limit? Say if the application sensed that the size of the downloadable file is higher than 1mb, it will automatically cancel/stop the download.

Answer (score 1):

Due to security policy JavaScript only has access to elements within the window it was launched from and the windows that it has launched.

Download dialogues are launched by the browser itself not by JavaScript. The browser could choose to not launch a download dialogue and launch a rendering window instead. For ex. PDFs in firefox are forced as a download while in chrome they are displayed to the user you. If you had a browser plugin in firefox for PDF rendering you wouldn't get the download dialogue there either.

You can cut the download to whatever length you want it from the server side. Write a script that reads the contents of the file to be transferred, transfer it in chunks and stop when the sum of the sizes of the chunks is greater or equal to the desired size.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually it is for an internet cafe. Since I could not configure the router to ban all downloads (since we need the auto-update of some programs). I just wonder if this is possible with javascript.

Comment: The short answer is no. There might be some browser plug-ins created just for that or you could make your own browser plug-in just for that because browser plug-ins do not have the aforementioned security restrictions.